# Forget to bind object to App

Tags: apex, visualforce

I just created a object but forget to bind this object to any app.
How can I bind this object to any app ?
I tried to edit that object but there is no such option.

Actually  I forget to tick checkbox ''Launch New Custom Tab Wizard after saving this custom object'' while creating a object as can seen in the below screenshot:
[image]

So there is no tab for this object.So when I go to apps and tried to look that tab it is not there as can seen in the below screenshot:
[image]

So how can I add that object under any app which does not have any tab ?

Comment: Have you looking at the Salesforce help and training around Salesforce Apps? That should help you add an object to the app.

Comment: what do you mean by bind object to app?

Comment: Once you create an object, you can't directly specify the Apps to associate the object/tab to. You'll have to edit each app and add the tab, or use the metadata API to perform an update. Go to Setup > Create > Apps, edit the App, and you can then add the tab to that App.

Comment: In addition to @sfdcfox comment, you might also need to grant permissions to that object via either Profile Permissions or Permission Sets. If you've used the Add App button under Getting Started in the Setup menu, a Permission Set is created for you.

Comment: Hi guys, I just modify my question for better clarity. Please have a look again and suggest something.

Comment: Create a tab. Add new tab to desired apps

Comment: Thanks Eric for solving my problem. Also thanks to sfdcfox and Dan Jones for your response.